# Vue 3 + Vuetify 3 + TypeScript - How to access to the vuetify props definition?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I want to access to the Vuetify 3 props definition of VSelect component. So I will be able to set the same definition to my custom component.

Here is the code for my custom element :

```
<template>
    <v-select v-bind="{ ...$attrs, ...$props }">
        <template v-for="(_, name) in $slots" v-slot:[name]="slotData"><slot :name="name" v-bind="slotData"></slot></template>
    </v-select>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { VSelect as test } from 'vuetify/components/VSelect';

defineProps<test>();
// ERROR : [plugin:vite:vue] [@vue/compiler-sfc] type argument passed to defineProps() must be a literal type, or a reference to an interface or literal type.

</script>
```

Comment: did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Importing type for `defineProps<T>()` is currently not supported. See [Limitations](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-props)

You can import the props object and pass it to `defineProps(objectHere)`

Comment: Alright, but how to import the props from VSelect ? I have tried this solution, but I am still stuck at this point.

Comment: This wil only work if vuetify explicitly exports the props. Many packages like naive-ui do this.

Answer (score 0):

It was a limitation of Vue before version 3.3. defineProps could only accept types declared in the same file, but not imported types. Now, when Vue 3.3 is released, you can update Vue version and get rid of this inconvenience. Quote from [Announcing Vue 3.3 blog post](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3-3):

> Previously, types used in the type parameter position of defineProps and defineEmits were limited to local types, and only supported type literals and interfaces. This is because Vue needs to be able to analyze the properties on the props interface in order to generate corresponding runtime options. This limitation is now resolved in 3.3. The compiler can now resolve imported types, and supports a limited set of complex types:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import type { Props } from './foo'

// imported + intersection type
defineProps<Props & { extraProp?: string }>()
</script>
```